# How to INSERT in a table that is in a Postgres schema with Sequel?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, insert, sequel

According to the [Sequel document](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sequel/4.38.0/Sequel%2FDatabase:schema), this is the syntax to insert data into DB.

```
DB[:items].insert
# INSERT INTO items DEFAULT VALUES
```

If the table `items` is created in `some_schema`. The SQL command is

```
INSERT INTO some_schema.items DEFAULT VALUES
```

What is the syntax when using Sequel? I tried some ways but it doesn't work.

E.g

```
DB[:some_schema][:items].insert
```

```
DB[:some_schema.items].insert
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good way to do what you want.  have you looked at migrations?: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Comment: I'm using Sequel so I just want to know the syntax for INSERT. 
I know the syntax for SELECT is like this
`DB.from{schema[:table]} # SELECT * FROM schema.table`
so I think there might be a way for INSERT as well.

Answer (score 0):

After researching, I found a way.
We need to connect with DB and set the search path to the schema.

```
DB = Sequel.connect(adapter, host, database, search_path: "some_schema", user, password)
```

And then you can call direct to the table `items`, not `some_schema.items` anymore.